# Category(#35300) expected, got "1" which is an instance of String(#5180)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

I have a `Tournament` model with an association to `Category`:

```
has_one :category_id, class_name: "Category", optional: true
```

Its database schema is:

```
 create_table "tournaments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "start_at"
    t.datetime "end_at"
    # ...
    t.integer "category_id"
  end
```

and for some reason, I'm getting a type mismatch error after submitting the create form:

```
<div class="mt-4">
  <%= f.label "Select tournament game", class: "block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700" %>
  <div class="mt-1 rounded-md shadow-sm">
    <%= f.select(:category_id, Category.all.map{|c| [c.name, c.id]}, {prompt: true, selected: :category_id}, {class: "ts_select block form-select w-full transition duration-150 ease-in-out sm:text-sm sm"}) %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the error and the data passed when the request was made

```
Started POST "/tournaments" for ::1 at 2020-07-10 00:51:10 +0100
Processing by TournamentsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"s7itTc9N+7UkNjYGjkukaZ51NvS3ZfVnrpvLC2xl2umCHsypJN/clhezKX7JZ5bPsZfcUVXeFH9FCJroLkoeZg==", "tournament"=>{"name"=>"test tournament", "country"=>"US", "start_at(3i)"=>"9", "start_at(2i)"=>"7", "start_at(1i)"=>"2020", "start_at(4i)"=>"23", "start_at(5i)"=>"50", "end_at(3i)"=>"9", "end_at(2i)"=>"7", "end_at(1i)"=>"2020", "end_at(4i)"=>"23", "end_at(5i)"=>"50", "featured_player_id"=>"", "stream_link"=>"nickmercs", "highlight_clip"=>"SneakyBenevolentFennelGOWSkull", "prize"=>"20000", "category_id"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Create Tournament"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.4ms | Allocations: 2814)

ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch (Category(#35300) expected, got "1" which is an instance of String(#5180)):

activerecord (6.0.3.2) lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:283:in `raise_on_type_mismatch!'
activerecord (6.0.3.2) lib/active_record/associations/belongs_to_association.rb:66:in `replace'
activerecord (6.0.3.2) lib/active_record/associations/singular_association.rb:17:in `writer'
activerecord (6.0.3.2) lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:108:in `category_id='
...
```

I've checked all instances of "Category" and "category_id" and only `category_id` is being used in tournaments.

Comment: Are you looking for `has_one` instead of `belongs_to`?

Comment: @JuJoDi A tournament should only have one category yes, so I tried swapping it to  `has_one` and I got the following `Unknown key: :optional. Valid keys are: :class_name, :anonymous_class, :foreign_key, :validate, :autosave, :foreign_type, :dependent, :primary_key, :inverse_of, :required, :as, :touch`

Comment: Updated @JuJoDi based with your suggestion and added the table schema

Answer (score 1):

Correct association with your database schema would be

```
belongs_to :category, optional: true
```

EDIT: as a reference https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-belongs-to-and-has-one